# .htaccess RewriteRule for single file besides index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to write a .htaccess script for a single file, `viewprofile.php`, which has one parameter, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^viewprofile$ viewprofile.php?mem=$1 [QSA, L]
RewriteRule ^viewprofile$ /viewprofile.php?mem=$1 [QSA, L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

Ideally what I'd like would be for results to show up as `www.example.com/viewprofile/JHFSD667` without interfering with the index.php file. Both `viewprofile.php` and `index.php` are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the space in `[QSA, L]`.

Then you have to add a capture group to get the profile into `mem`.

Optionally, you could use only one rule for your `index.php` by adding `/?`.

```
RewriteRule ^viewprofile/([\w\d]+)$ viewprofile.php?mem=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```